# Azure Websites Authentication / Authorization

Tags: authentication, azure

I am using new feature of Azure that enables the active directory authentication for your website without writing any code.
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/13/azure-websites-authentication-authorization/

But the problem is my web application is also hosting some Web APIs, which need to be called without any authentication.

Is there a way (some attributes?) so that I can call Web APIs without any authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tushar, I see that Byron also replied to your question on his post- and suggested creating another website as for APIs as a work around. However I suggest that you wire-up auth separately for your Web App and APIs following our samples here: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet, https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet

Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Thanks Dushyant, I am wiring up auth separately now. Do you have any AzureADSample where microsoft live account is used for authentication. I have added microsoft live ids to my AzureAD and I want my web app to authenticate against it.

Comment: If you're using OpenIDConnect then sign-in for MSA guest users will be available automatically. As soon as the MSA users enter their username, they should get redirected to the MSA signin age to authenticate, and your app will receive a token from AzureAD for the MSA guest user.

Answer (score 1):

From the very same article you refer:

> **Current Limitations**
>
> There are some limitation to the current preview
> release of this feature:
>
> ...
>
> With the current release the whole site is placed behind login the
> requirement.
>
> Head less authentication/authorization for API scenarios
> or service to service scenarios are not currently supported.

So, no, you cannot have partial APIs or pages anonymously available - all pages and API will be protected by the Azure Active Directory.